# How to count the number of clocks of some given duration?

Tags: org-mode, events

I want to collect statistics about some clocked events; more specifically I need to count the number of clocked events (belonging to some subtree for instance) whose duration is in some predefined range (e.g. at least 4 hours but less than 5 hours).

For instance, in the following subtree

`*** Week 11 [2018-03-10 Sat] → [2018-03-16 Fri]
   :CLOCKBOOK:
    CLOCK: [2018-03-16 Fri 09:00]--[2018-03-16 Fri 13:45] =>  4:45
    CLOCK: [2018-03-15 Thu 09:00]--[2018-03-15 Thu 13:30] =>  4:30
    CLOCK: [2018-03-13 Tue 09:00]--[2018-03-13 Tue 13:45] =>  4:45
    CLOCK: [2018-03-12 Mon 09:00]--[2018-03-12 Mon 14:00] =>  5:00
    CLOCK: [2018-03-10 Sat 18:00]--[2018-03-10 Sat 21:00] =>  3:00
    :END:`

The function should return `3`
How could I achieve this?

Comment: I don't see why you used the `org-mode` tag, so I removed it. If it is relevant, please consider updating the question to show the relevance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my-count-clocks` in the following Elisp section defines a function that counts clocks in the current org-mode section. It does not descent into sub-sections. You can easily modify `my-count-clocks` to fit your special needs, e.g., work recursive on sub-sections.

That function has a predicate function as argument. The predicate gets a timestamp as argument and should return non-nil if that timestamp is to be counted.

An example for such a timestamp is given as `my-pred`. `my-pred` is non-nil for timestamps that tick at least 4 hours and shorter than 5 hours.

The other functions in the Elisp code are just helpers.

```el
(defun org-element-parse-headline (&optional granularity visible-only)
  "Parse current headline.
GRANULARITY and VISIBLE-ONLY are like the args of `org-element-parse-buffer'."
  (let ((level (org-current-level)))
    (org-element-map
    (org-element-parse-buffer granularity visible-only)
    'headline
      `(lambda (el)
     (and
      (eq (org-element-property :level el) ,level)
      (<= (org-element-property :begin el) (point))
      (<= (point) (org-element-property :end el))
      el))
      nil 'first-match 'no-recursion)))

(defun my-count-clocks (pred)
  "Counting clocks fulfilling PRED in current subsection."
  (interactive "a Predicate:")
  (let* ((headline (org-element-parse-headline))
     (section (org-element-map
              headline
              'section
            #'identity
            nil 'first-match))
     (clocks (org-element-map section 'clock (lambda (clock) (org-element-property :value clock))))
     (num (cl-count-if pred clocks)))
    (when (called-interactively-p 'any)
      (message "Number of clocks: %d" num))
    num))

(eval
 `(defun decode-time-subtract (a b)
    "Decode time difference between A and B."
    (cl-mapcar #'-
           (decode-time (time-subtract a b))
           ',(butlast (decode-time '(0 0)) 3))))

(defun my-pred (timestamp)
  "Example predicate.
Non-nil for timestamp that clicks at least 4 hours and less than 5 hours."
  (let ((b (org-timestamp--to-internal-time timestamp))
    (e (org-timestamp--to-internal-time timestamp t)))
    (cl-multiple-value-bind (sec minute hour day month year) (decode-time-subtract e b)
      ;; Put the condition of your choice here:
      (and (eq year 0) (eq month 0) (eq day 0)
       (>= hour 4)
       (< hour 5))
      )))
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot